# Laravel 5.8 CSRF token mismatch

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing an App using laravel, after I upload my files on the live server all the post request was CSRF token mismatch. But the thing is it is not happening on my local machine.

[image]

Comment: are you sure you have set the token every time you refresh the page and not used the static one.?

Comment: can you share to JS code as well.?

Comment: yes, before is everything is going well. but all of the sudden it shows the error. i include the always the token

Comment: my conclusion is that it didn't  match the token from the form

Answer (score 0):

put token in your ajax.

```
$.post(base_url + "url_name", {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}, function (data) {

}
```